# Macro stops prematurely

Tags: excel, vba

Macro to keep on going to the next cell till the value doesn't match and for all the similar values, subtract the values from the bottom most row

Essentially my data is like this (There is only one buy for each name and it is the bottom most cell)

```
Name |   Transaction.Type |  Amount | Remaining (what macro needs to do)       

Name1 |      Sell  |         5    |     15 (20-5)

Name1  |    Sell    |       10     |      10 (20-10)

Name1   |   Sell     |      15     |     5  (20-15)

Name1   |   Buy    |        20       |

Name2  |    Sell    |       25      |      5

Name2   |   Buy     |       30        |
```

So far my macro looks like

```
Dim sline As Integer
Dim eline As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastrow(1 To 3) As Long
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Worksheets("Testing Data 2")
lastrow(1) = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With


 For i = 2 To 4151
   If Worksheets("Testing Data 2").Range("A" & i) <> Worksheets("Testing Data 2").Range("A" & i).Offset(1, 0) Then
    eline = i

    Worksheets("Testing Data 2").Range(":C" & eline)        

    'struggling to go from here

    End If
 Next i
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Are you sure it is ending early? It doesn't appear to actually be doing anything. You mention a range but then never assign a action to that range. Also, no need for the `eline` variable. It is the exact same thing as `i`. Just use `Range("C" & i)`

Comment: oh I am still writing this, a bit of guidance would be appreciated in terms of how to substract from the bottom most row where the values match

Comment: Oh I have made sure, buy is always the last cell and there is one buy for each name

Comment: I don't have to search for a name because  Worksheets("Testing Data 2").Range("A" & i) <> Worksheets("Testing Data 2").Range("A" & i).Offset will just see if the values differ because all similar names are congregated together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without VBA with the understanding that each `Name` only has one instnace of `Buy`

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A3,B:B,"Buy")-C2      'Drag down as needed
```

---

[image]

Comment: Or, you can copy this logic into VBA if needed for your purposes. You can drop formula and then paste as text or access these formulas via `WorksheetFunctions.SUMIFS(....`